# Mysql left join to check record using the where clause in only one table

Tags: mysql, left-join

Am trying to check if the user viewing the current product has already bought the product before by checking if the `product.pid` exist in table `order.opid` or not. The below query work without adding `AND o.buyer = 'peter'` in where clause, but is very important that i validate the query against the user currently viewing the product.

Products

```
pid   | pname 
------|--------------
100   | Toyota
200   | Lexus
```

order

```
oid  | opid  | buyer  | opname  | color
-----|-------|------------------|-------
M10  | 100   | peter  |Toyota   | red
M11  | 100   | peter  |Toyota   | black
M12  | 100   | john   |Toyota   | black
M13  | 200   | peter  |Lexus    | black
```

SQL QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN order o
ON p.pid = o.opid
WHERE p.pid = 100
AND o.buyer = 'peter'
```

Comment: And what is it that doesn't work when you add the buyer check to the WHERE clause? Please ***edit your question*** and include the results you expect, and the ones you're getting. [I created an SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/502ba/5) (had to use Oracle because MySQL isn't working on SQLFiddle right now) and it looks to me like it was giving the correct results - but as I say, I don't know what your expectations are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition on the second table needs to go in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products p LEFT JOIN
     order o
     ON p.pid = o.opid AND o.buyer = 'peter'
WHERE p.pid = 100;
```

This may seem rather arcane, but the rule is easy to learn.  A `left join` keeps all rows in the first table, regardless of whether the `ON` clause evaluates to true, false, or `NULL`.  However, the values from the second table become `NULL`, so the `WHERE` clause filters out the unmatched buyers, turning the outer join into an inner join.

The same reasoning explains why conditions on the *first* table should go in the `WHERE` clause and not the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with the query.

I ran the above query

```
SELECT * FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN order o
ON p.pid = o.opid
WHERE p.pid = 100
AND o.buyer = 'peter'
```

and it is resulting in response only when buyer is **peter**.

But its not an optimized query as here you are fetching first all results even when data is not present in order table with null as buyer and other info and then with where clause optimizing it to remove the one where buyer is not peter. Instead,

```
SELECT * FROM Products p  INNER JOIN order1 o ON p.pid = o.opid WHERE p.pid = 1 AND o.buyer = 'peter'
```

INNER JOIN returns all intersection data of two tables. and then where clause filters where buyer is peter

I would suggest one omtimization though in your query, don't use buyer name instead create a mapping table for user and store userId as there will be many users with same name. Its better to normalize the table.